# T-SQL Get Events after an order

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

So I have data that looks like this:

[image: sample data]

What I am trying to do in SQL is get all of the `CollectedDT` that are later than a date and less than a date, for example all of the values in yellow in both columns belong together, the records with just one column in yellow I don't care about and the ones in all green are keepers too. The idea is to try and implicitly say that one set of collection times belong to an order and another set belong to the other. There is no rule for hours difference between each, could be 1 hour, could be 100 hours.

While the query returned what it should have, it is decipherable that the `CollectedDT` of `11-04-2011 15:35` and newer most likely belongs to the `11-03-2011 21:12` order, there is no hard logic to dictate this, it is simply implied and needs to be treated as such.

Really no good starting point on how to go from here.

The query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT ORD.[episode_no],
    ORD.[ord_no],
    ORD.[pty_name] AS 'Ordering Provider',
    ORD.[ent_dtime] AS 'Order Entered',
    ASMT.[CollectedDT],
    ORD.[str_dtime],
    ORD.last_cng_dtime,
    PMS.vst_start_dtime AS 'Admit Dt',
    PMS.[vst_end_dtime] AS 'Discharge Dt',
    ORD.[ord_qty],
    CASE 
        WHEN ORD.[ord_sts] = 27
            THEN 'Complete'
        WHEN ORD.ord_sts = 34
            THEN 'Discontinued'
        ELSE ORD.ord_sts
        END AS 'Order Status',
    ORD.[desc_as_written],
    ASMT.[FormUsage] AS 'Assessment',
    ASMT.[AssessmentID],
    datediff(minute, ORD.ent_dtime, ASMT.CollectedDT) AS [order_entry_to_collected_minutes],
    datediff(hour, ORD.ent_dtime, ASMT.CollectedDT) AS [order_entry_to_collected_hours]
FROM [SMSPHDSSS0X0].[smsmir].[mir_sr_ord] AS ORD
LEFT OUTER JOIN [smsmir].[mir_sr_vst_pms] AS PMS ON PMS.episode_no = ORD.episode_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN [smsmir].[mir_sc_Assessment] AS ASMT ON ASMT.PatientVisit_oid = PMS.vst_no
WHERE (ORD.desc_as_written LIKE 'physical Therapy%')
    AND (
        ASMT.FormUsage IN ('Physical Therapy Initial Asmt', 'Physical Therapy Re-evaluation', 'PT Flowsheet')
        AND ASMT.CollectedDT > ORD.ent_dtime
        )
    AND ORD.ord_sts = 27
    AND ASMT.AssessmentStatus = 'Complete'
```

Comment: Those aliases are somewhat odd. `a` for `mir_sr_ord`? `b` for `mir_sr_vst_pms`? None of those letter appear in the names of the objects. Use meaningful aliases. Also make sure you qualify all your column names. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator Your highlighted records don't make it clear what the logic is behind when to select a record and when to ignore it.

Comment: @RyanWilson no, not necessarily 24 hours, could be any n hours, I just don't want to see records where the CollectedDT is greater than the Order Entered if they are also greater than the next Order Entered

Comment: What are you actually asking for help with?

Comment: @Andrew how to filter out the rows where only a single column is in yellow.

Comment: I'm not seeing a difference between your rows in green, and the unhighlighted rows in yellow.  For all values in CollectedDT, they're greater than their respective OrderEntered value, and they're greater than the previous value.  Can you clarify the logic on which records you want?

Comment: "there is no hard logic to dictate this" If you cannot describe how to do it, how can you tell a machine to do it? The only logic I can possibly think of is that you want to exclude rows for which there is a `CollectedDT` on the same day as the earliest `Order Entered` for each distinct `ord_no`